# How to find no of times button has been clicked in a particular time frame(within 0.5 second)

Tags: reactjs

My requirements:

- I want to rewind a player when I click on rewind button.
- If I click button once then it should rewind by 10 seconds.
- But if I click in quick succession (within 0.5 second) then it should rewind accordingly.

Like if I clicked 2 times in quick succession then it should rewind by 20 seconds and so on.

How to do it in React.js?

Comment: Did you attempt to write some code implementing what you are describing? If yes, please share it with us.

Comment: I improved the wording/structure of your question, but allow a hint: questions going "here requirements, now somebody tell me how to get there", often don't work out here. Instead: do some research, and try to solve the problem yourself. And then, when you have same actual code, then you are welcome to write up a question about that. You learn much more by doing such things yourself first.